# how to disable a super view while clicking a button on subview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

Here I have a button in UITableViewCell. If I click button the another view should popup. If I click the same button then the view should be disable. Please help me out from this. Thanks in advance.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell       =   (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell                    =   [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
        cell.frame              =   CGRectZero;
        cell.backgroundColor    =   [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.selectionStyle     =   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

        UILabel* label                  =   [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 250, 50)];
        label.font                      =   [UIFont lightFontWithSize:14];
        label.textAlignment             =   NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        label.textColor                 =   [UIColor blackColor];
        label.highlightedTextColor      =   [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.numberOfLines             =   2;
        label.tag                       =   1;

        ForumDBFilePath* currObj = [forumResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currObj.postcontent];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont regularFontWithSize:15];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        UIBackgroundButton* replyButton = [UIBackgroundButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [replyButton setButtonColor:[UIColor whiteColor] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor getNavBarColor]];
        [replyButton setTitle:@"Reply" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         replyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [replyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont mediumFontWithSize:14]];
        [replyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth-0, 15, 125, 30)];
        [replyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(replyButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [replyButton resignFirstResponder];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:replyButton];
    }
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override superview method like this:

```
- (id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return hitView;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.